# Mixed Hyper-V environment Server 2008 & Server 2008 R2 with VMM and VMM R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a few Server 2008 Hyper-V hosts all working fine with Virtual Machine Manager. I got a new server and installed Server 2008 R2 and was unable to manage it with VMM; so I upgraded to VMM R2. Now, I am unable to manage any of my old Server 2008 machines, but the Server 2008 R2 machine works great.

Is there a way to use System Center Virtual Machine Manager in a mixed Server2008/Server2008R2 environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mixed environment you describe is indeed a supported environment for VMM 2008 R2 ([this FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221383.aspx) lists the supported virtualization platforms).

I would suggest reviewing the steps outlined in [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/chengw/archive/2009/08/24/vmm-2008-r2-upgrade-guide.aspx) on TechNet to make sure you didn't miss anything (particularly the post-upgrade update of each of the managed entities with the new agent).

Additional details regarding the VMM upgrade process can be found in the [VMM 2008 R2 Deployment Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=139191) in VMM TechNet.